# Unable to use Format Document tool for VSCode when coding in HTML. No problems with Python

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, format

I am using VSCode to learn web design as I have used VSCode in the past for Python. While I was coding in Python, the document format tool worked just fine, even the though I moved on to PyCharm.
Now that I am using VSCode for HTML/CSS, the format tool just doesn't seem to work at all. I tried adding the prettier extension and adding it as the default format tool, but that didn't work. Beyond just reinstalling VScode, is there something I missed. Thanks.

Again, I tried adding the prettier extension to the default format tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an enthusiast, hope these will help.

- Re-install & restart VSCode
- Check settings to see if you actually activated it
- ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The prettier extension requires a little bit of configuration to work. First you need to make sure it’s your default formatter. In the settings on the top right there will be a button for viewing settings in json format. click it then add this to the file

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
}
```

Then you will probably want to format on save. Add this as well:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

That should get it working.

Comment: I guess you mean ""editor.formatOnSave": true"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is a problem with the html code.
Try create a new .html file and copy this basic HTML code and see if it gets formatted correctly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>


  </body>

  
</html>
```